# How to set warnings when time is almost up on DateTime

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, datetime, controller

I have due_dates as a column in my db and its a Datetime format.  I want my rails app to be able to detect when there is a day left or an hour left etc. based on the `datetime` value.  every request will have a due date so each datetime will be unique.  I know how to make notifications I just don't know how to make the timer aspect or however you're suppose to detect these `datetimes` before or exactly when they pass the date.

ex.
 today <-- 11/5/2016 |(one day)| 11/6/2016 <--duedate     **db update/ send notification "one day left"**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether now is before or exactly the duedate

```
if DateTime.now <= duedate
    # do something
end
```

---

to show the distance in word like `one day left` or `one hour` use could use this

```
# if needed, include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(duedate)
```

---

So

```
if DateTime.now <= duedate
    @distance_in_words = distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(duedate)
    # something else to setup the notification
end
```

Comment: okay I see what youre doing!! ^^ thank you! Is there a controller that is always reloading so that it can catch it? cause if i just make a method, i still have to call the method.  I guess what im sayin is; is there a method that auto reloads like everyminute or automatically loads on the platform/application side not the client side?

Comment: for doing that, you might want to look at this I think https://github.com/javan/whenever